# What causes a double peak for a single wavelength when using an optical spectrometer system?

Tags: optics, diffraction, spectroscopy, hydrogen, photon-emission

I am doing an experiment to determine the Rydberg constant for the Balmer series using an optical spectrometer system (consisting of a monochromator with a photomultiplier detector and pulse counting electronics). The first part of the experiment involves calibrating the system with a green laser of known wavelength. I have plotted the results for 3 different slit widths for this laser and I want to know why the slit width of 25μm has a flat top and why the slit width of 50μm has two peaks when the laser should have a single wavelength?

[image]